# What’s the difference between EAX, EBX, and ECX in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I’m trying to learn some assembly, but I have a hard time understanding what some basic things do. Are EAX, EBX, and ECX just variables or do they all have a unique specific use other than storing values?

Comment: These are the different processor registers. There are no variables in assembly language. You should read a thorough introduction into assembly to learn these basics...

Comment: @Erlkoenig okay, thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` and so on are actually **registers**, which can be seen as *"hardware"* variables, somewhat similar to higher level-language's variables. Registers can be used in your software directly with instructions such as `mov`, `add` or `cmp`. The leading `e` stands for **e**xtended and means that your register is 32 bits wide. On the other hand, 64-bit registers begin with `r`.

These registers are not always used for the purposes illustrated below. This graphic shows the register usage for Linux 64-bit [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

[image: Linux 64-bit ABI]

Not all registers are described in this capture though. For instance `*ip`is a special register ([process counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter)) that holds the next instruction to be executed.

You can find the [full ABI there.](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) Some information is specific to Linux but most remains relevant for any [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compliant system.

Comment: full ABI there (link broken) : https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf

Comment: Note that some instructions have implied registers (`mul`, `div`, `cwd`, `xlat`, `movsb/w/d`, `loop`, `rdtsc`, ...), which is important when choosing registers (especially in the middle of a routine); and an ABI is mostly irrelevant in pure assembly (when you're not mixing assembly with another language like C and aren't forced to comply with whatever a different language's compiler expects).

Answer (score 10):

The **EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, EBP, EDI**, and **ESI** registers are all 32-bit general-purpose registers, used for temporary data storage and memory access.

https://web.archive.org/web/20191114093028/https://gerardnico.com/computer/cpu/register/general

Some of CPU instructions modify specific registers. For instance, `movsb` takes **S**ource address from **ESI** and **D**estination from **EDI**, copies one byte and changes ESI and EDI registers.

In other words, you could use them as variables, but they also might have a specific purpose when using specific instructions.

You may want to consult the reference. Both Intel and AMD provide manuals, available online.